# Trying to read json object in php always returns "undefined"

Tags: php, node.js, json

I'm sending a POST request in Node.js to a php server. In the request i include the json as an object and not as a string.

Node.js request:

```
var request = require('request');

let data = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };

request.post({
  headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
  url: 'http://0.0.0.0:9000/html.php',
  method: 'POST',
  json: data
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

html.php:

```php
<?php
# Get JSON as an object
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$name = $json->name;

echo $json // Prints out the whole json correctly
echo $name; // Prints out "undefined"
```

I expect the output to be "John" instead of "undefined"

Comment: undefined is a js error - there's an error in your js that PHP outputs -not an error in your PHP

Comment: may also be worth vardumping the $json to see what's actually there

Comment: @treyBake it's an error in php because it can print out the whole json correctly. it's just elements of this json that are undefined

Comment: `$json` is a string. You need to decode before use: `json_decode($json);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, i've already tried that but it doesn't work because, as i said, i'm sending the JSON as an object not as a string.

Comment: @sergiu.siminiuc I assure you - it can't be

Comment: PLEASE SHOW US the output from `echo $json`

Comment: There is no way you can send the JSON as an object. You already proved you sent a string with `echo $json;`

Comment: _In the request i include the json as an object_ You cant do that even if you try!

Comment: Please `var_dump($json);` and add to question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly https://imgur.com/h1NN9sS

Comment: ARE YOU SURE that is the output from the `echo $json;` ??

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes. https://imgur.com/BNnTtPs

Answer (score 0):

When you get the JSON, it comes to you as a string (as you proved with `echo $json`). To make it into an object you must decode it:

```
# Get JSON as an object
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonObject = json_decode($json);

$name = $jsonObject->name;

echo $json // Prints out a string
echo $name;
```

[EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4ce46e9ff3b63bd6fb55d795c3d9d1dcb2ce43c)

Comment: Getting: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (( even though the 'example' link works

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($json,true); 
echo $data['name'];
```

This will work for you.

The `true` parameter will convert the json to an array. If you don't use it then it will convert it to an object meaning that you access the nested elements using the `->`

Something similar to:

```
$data = json_decode($json); 
echo $data->name;
```

This is the difference between using `true` as a second parameter in `json_decode` function. I think you mixed a bit there that's why it did not work for you.

Comment: BTW - wasn't my DV.

Comment: yes after you told him but he did not have it work based on what he said. As i explained in my answer i think he confused the second parameter in decoding and tried to access an array as an object or the opposite. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: No one made him aware of the `true` argument for the function, until your answer. Now, off to get more coffee! Cheers! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: wrote exactly like that but still getting 'undefined' ((